NestJS GraphQL Federation 2, problem with @ResolveReference between two services
I need help.
I currently have nestjs graphql microservices (apollo) federated via a nestjs gateway (appollo gateway).
The types are shared between the services via a library that shares the types (I'm in an NX monorepo).
Between services when I use @ResolveField() it works fine. I.e., if I use it from a service other than the base resolver I receive the input, if I use it from the base resolver I receive the complete response issued by the resolver.
Where I have a problem is when I want to use @ResolveReference(). For example in my use case:
I have a HelloEventDto object which is get from a Query on its own resolver from the scheduled-event-service.
From the sport-service, I would like to add the away_team and home_team fields.
To do this I need to use @ResolveReference() because I can't retrieve them with the current input and the ids are stored in the HelloEventDto object that I get from the base.
The current behaviour is that my scheduled-event-service behaves as it should. I.e. it renders the basic object and calls @ResolveField(). But my sport-service doesn't ping at all on the @resolveReference()
Here's how I'm trying to implement it:
HelloEventDto
@ObjectType()
@Directive('@key(fields: "scheduled_event_id")')
@Directive('@shareable')
export class HelloEventDto {
  @Field(() => ID)
  scheduled_event_id: string;

  @Field()
  ws_connected: boolean;

  @Field(() => ScheduledEventDto)
  scheduled_event: ScheduledEventDto; // here we can find away_sport_team_id and home_sport_team_id

  @Field(() => SportTeamDto)
  away_sport_team: SportTeamDto; // I wan add this with my sport-service with @ResolveReference()
}

SportTeamId with BaseDto
@ObjectType()
@Directive('@shareable')
export class BaseDto {
  @Field(() => ID)
  id: string;

  @Field()
  created_at: Date;

  @Field()
  updated_at: Date;
}


@ObjectType()
@Directive('@key(fields: "id")')
@Directive('@shareable')
export class SportTeamDto extends BaseDto {
  @Field()
  created_by_id: string;

  @Field()
  name: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  logo?: string;

  @Field()
  external_id: string;

  @Field(() => [String])
  home_team_of: string[];

  @Field(() => [String])
  away_team_of: string[];
}

HelloEvent Resolver on scheduled-event-service
@Resolver((of) => HelloEventDto)
@UseGuards(GQLAuthGuard)
export class HelloEventResolver {
  log = new Logger(HelloEventResolver.name);

  constructor(
    private readonly cls: ClsService,
    private scheduledEventService: ScheduledEventService
  ) {}

  @Public()
  @Query(() => HelloEventDto)
  async helloScheduledEvent(@Args('data') data: GetUniqueInputDto) {
    this.log.debug(`helloScheduledEvent: ${data.id}`);
    const scheduled_event = await this.scheduledEventService.get(data);
    return {
      ws_connected: false,
      scheduled_event_id: scheduled_event.id,
      scheduled_event,
      active_interactions: [],
    };
  }

  @ResolveField((of) => SportTeamDto)
  async away_sport_team(@Parent() data: HelloEventDto) {
    console.log('RESOLVE FIELD away_team FOR', data);
    return {
      __typename: SportTeamDto.name,
      id: data.scheduled_event.sport_event.away_sport_team_id,
    };
  }
}

SportTeam Resolver on sport-service
@Resolver((of) => SportTeamDto)
@UseGuards(GQLAuthGuard)
export class SportTeamResolver {
  constructor(
    private readonly cls: ClsService,
    private sportTeamService: SportTeamService
  ) {}

  @ResolveReference()
  resolveReference(reference: { __typename: string; id: string }) {
    console.log('ResolveReference SportTeamDto', reference);
    return this.sportTeamService.get({ id: reference.id });
  }

  @Query(() => SportTeamDto)
  async getSportTeam(@Args('data') data: GetUniqueInputDto) {
    return await this.sportTeamService.get(data);
  }
}

Thank you in advance for your help.
We look forward to hearing from you.
If you have any questions or require further information, please do not hesitate to contact me.

Can you add how you are calling the API and what object you are expecting please?

I found a solution to my problem this morning. It comes from the way I share types in my services. I'm going to write a bug fix later today with all the details.
